# Ten. Million. Questions. Any specific reason for this punctuation?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

> Ten. Million. Questions. Let's celebrate all we've done together.

Any special reason for those periods showing there after Ten and Million, at least on a mobile? Just curious.

Comment: too much beeeeeeer?

Comment: aha that's so plausible!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To. Give. This. Emphasis!

It is a [method of writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/name-and-origin-of-writing-with-period-after-each-word) to convey that the words are pronounced with pauses for emphasis, because reaching this milestone is a Really Big Deal (and that was an example of using only capitals to emphasise something).

Comment: Either that or they could have used all caps, but doubt that would go over well.

Comment: @CRABOLO ALL CAPS gets detected by the [Smoke Detector](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3867303#3867303) and as a result we will delete it, if needed the complete site...

Comment: @rene: Does smoke detecter also detect CRABOLO? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the answer of Martjin Pieters that it is used to emphasis the statement and to the surprise I found it on one of the stake exchange site check this out.

[Name and origin of writing with period after each word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/name-and-origin-of-writing-with-period-after-each-word)

It simply adds a *pause* between each word to read it this way.

> Ten`[wait for a second]`Million`[wait for a second]`Questions`[wait for a second]`

Comment: Now that is more like you are dying. "Ten.... Million.... Questions.... To be found in the castle of Aaargh....."

Comment: @JanFabry Haha Right quite a bit but read it differently.Updating..